# Puppeteer Weird Behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

```
let tableRowsExists = true;
let tableRowsCounter = 0;
let tableRows = [];
while (tableRowsExists) {
  const tableRow = await page.$$(
    "tr.oddsRow111-" + tableRowsCounter + ".sprmr.tr-hover"
  );
  console.log("tr.oddsRow111-" + tableRowsCounter + ".sprmr.tr-hover");
  console.log(tableRow);
  tableRowsCounter += 1;
  }
}
```

Hi Everyone!
Does anyone know why this puppeteer gives me back different results
every time i launch the same functions?
In details, i'm running a function that searches for some table rows.
I've found a pattern inside the class names of some tr tags.
As you can see, i've setted a counter that gives to the page.$() function
different class names every time.

Looking on the web site there are tr tags with the class name that
goes from  "tr.oddsRow111-0.sprmr.tr-hover" to
"tr.oddsRow111-9.sprmr.tr-hover".
But eveytime i run the code it is able to found something from counter
5 to 9, other times from 6 to 9 ecc...

Do you have any idea about the weird behavior of this code?

Comment: What site are you scraping? Sometimes sites don't always give the same data every time.

Comment: I'm scraping GoldBet (https://www.goldbet.it/scommesse-sportive/calcio/italia/serie-a/1-1577-93)

Comment: You can check the HTML if you want, but maybe you will need a Italian VPN (for the regulation the majority of the bookmakers are avaiable only with italian ip adress)